# Corollary of Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

I have a question on one of the corolarries of the Yoneda lemma. Let $y$ be the yoneda embedding. Then how can one prove for two objects $c, d\in C$ that if $y(c) \cong y(d) \Rightarrow c\cong d$.

I cant see how it immediately follows from the yoneda embedding.

Comment: The Yoneda embedding is fully faithfull. Prove that every fully faithfull functor $F$ reflects isomorphisms, meaning that, if $Ff$ is an isomorphism, then so is $f$.

Comment: Ah thank you, i actually know this but forgot to apply it to this case.